# Amazon S3: Use aws s3 cp without downloading existing files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way using the AWS CLI to download files using `--recursive` and `--exclude` + `--include` and no overwrite files I have already downloaded? It likes to just rewrite files even if they haven't changed, and won't resume downloads after a crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`sync` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). It assumes `--recursive` flag by default:

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
>   files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates
>   folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/path/to/folder/ . --exclude '*' --include 'filesToMatch*.txt'
```

As said by [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226549/8285811), `--recursive` is implied vs. `cp`.

And you can always include the `--dryrun` flag to verify what will run before actually executing it.